# Getting Json object to individual items in c# using linq

Tags: c#, json

```
  var respnse1 = client.GetAsync(hostmi).Result;
  string content1 = respnse1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
  JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(content1);
  JObject ojObject = (JObject)joResponse["usermachine"];
  JArray array = (JArray)joResponse["pInterval"];    
  var pLNo= (from p in array select ["pLocationNumber"]).ToList();
  var pLIny= (from p in array select p["pLocationInterval"]).ToList();
  // The following is not working
  Usermachine um = new Usermachine();
  um.employeeid = (string) ojObject["usermachine"]["employeeid"]; 
  um.employeename = (string)ojObject["usermachine"]["employeename"];
```

I am getting an error at the `um.employeeid = …` which is system null exception. 
I tried to see the content of `ojObject` in the immediate window as follows:

```
? ojObject
{
  "employeeid": "1123",
  "employeename": "EMP 001 NAME",
  "mMacID": "E0138",
  "machinename": "FOS",
  "iscleaning": 1,
  "isperforming": 1,
  "isverifying": 1,
  "cSeqno": 1,
  "cMacID": "E0138",
  "cInterval": 112,
  "cCleanOperationMaxTime": 300,
  "cPerformOperationMaxTime": 600,
  "oSequenceID": 6,
  "oMacID": "E0138",
  "oItemNumber": " ",
  "oBatchNumber": " ",
  "oPONumber": " ",
  "oCompletedOperation": 0,
  "oComplOperStartTime": 0,
  "oCompOperEndndTime": 0,
  "oOperationToContinue": 1
}
base: {
  "employeeid": "1123",
  "employeename": "EMP 001 NAME",
  "mMacID": "E0138",
  "machinename": "FOS",
  "iscleaning": 1,
  "isperforming": 1,
  "isverifying": 1,
  "cSeqno": 1,
  "cMacID": "E0138",
  "cInterval": 112,
  "cCleanOperationMaxTime": 300,
  "cPerformOperationMaxTime": 600,
  "oSequenceID": 6,
  "oMacID": "E0138",
  "oItemNumber": " ",
  "oBatchNumber": " ",
  "oPONumber": " ",
  "oCompletedOperation": 0,
  "oComplOperStartTime": 0,
  "oCompOperEndndTime": 0,
  "oOperationToContinue": 1
}
Type: Object
```

My objective is to get the `employeeid` and `employeename` if possible using a `select` (linq) query else even the above approach is OK if it works.

Comment: thnx Brian ;). I was floundering as a typical newbie. Learnt it now from your correction. Sorry for the trouble caused  to all with my earlier posts.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it working using Linq. As reference pasting the code below

```
var respnse1 = client.GetAsync(hostmi).Result;
string content1 = respnse1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(content1);
JObject ojObject = (JObject)joResponse["usermachine"];
JArray array = (JArray)joResponse["pInterval"];
```

The Json string is as follows :

```
{
"usermachine": {
    "employeeid": "1123",
    "employeename": "EMP 001 NAME" 
},
"pInterval": [
    {
        "pMachineID": "E0138",
        "pmachinetoLocationSequence": 1
    },
    {
        "pMachineID": "E0138",
        "pmachinetoLocationSequence": 2
    },
    {
        "pMachineID": "E0138",
        "pmachinetoLocationSequence": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

(I tried my best in formatting and pasting. Hope it sticks, still learning!!)
You will find that there is an array (pInterval ) as in  master / detail relationship tables.
Now to get the master data code as follows:

```
string employeeid   = (string) ojObject.SelectToken("employeeid");
string employeename = (string) ojObject.SelectToken("employeename");
```

Now to get the details data as follows

```
var pmachinetoLocationSequence= (from p in arrayselect p["pmachinetoLocationSequence"]).ToList();
foreach (var item in pmachinetoLocationSequence)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.Value<string>().ToString());
}
```

Is there a way to get multiple fields in the above var pmachinetoLocationSequence line ?